# Selenium RC - User Extension

Tags: eclipse, selenium-rc, user-extensions.js

Planning to calculate page response time using "Timer Extension" using http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Timer+Extension.

I have copied the code in "User-Extension.js" and updated the path in Selenium RC.

When I execute following code using eclipse, I am getting following error message "method timerStart(string) is undefined".

System.out.println("Test Strated");

timerStart("LoginPage");

selenium.open(BASE_URL_1);

selenium.waitForPageToLoad(MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MS);

timerStop("LoginPage");

How to make eclipse recognize this new method ?

-Bharath

Comment: Did you add usersExtensions from the command line? 

-userExtensions : indicates a JavaScript file that will be loaded into Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

The new method is added to Selenium's prototype. So I think you would have to do:

```
selenium.timerStart("LoginPage");
```